# Two ajax post calls with one submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Is this possible to do? I currently just do one post call.
I want to do a post call with username/password and another one with email/password with one submit button. If both succeeds, redirecting to another page would be best.

Ajax call with jQuery:

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: $('form').attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      alert("Login successful. Redirecting");
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "3.3.3.3/login"
      }, 5000);

    },
    error: function(data, status, xhr) {
      $('form').trigger("reset");
      alert("Failed to login. Please try again.");
    }
  });

  return false;
  alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Log In</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="1.1.1.1/login" method="POST">

    <div class="login">
      <div class="login-screen">
        <div class="app-title">
          <h1> Login</h1>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="eauth" value="pam">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="email" placeholder="email">

        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. I figure there is some bad backend choices there if you have to check with two different pages to figure out if the user can proceed?

But apart from that... I would probably just run the two ajax calls after each other. They will run async, and you will have little control over which will finish first, so you should just have a bool, like firstAjaxHasSucceeded, which will be true after either of the ajax calls succeed. And if it's already true, transfer the user to the other page (both ajax calls should check this also).

**EDIT**

Pseudo code (don't have time for anything else):

```js
var firstAjaxHasSucceeded = false;

firstAjaxCall() {
  var success = verifyThisAjaxAnswer();
  
  if (firstAjaxHasSucceeded && success) {
    //Transfer to next page, yeay!! 
  }
  
  firstAjaxHasSucceeded = true;
}

secondAjaxCall() {
  var success = verifyThisAjaxAnswer();
  
  if (firstAjaxHasSucceeded && success) {
    //Transfer to next page, yeay!! 
  }
  
  firstAjaxHasSucceeded = true;
}

firstAjaxCall();
secondAjaxCall();
```

Comment: Didnt have time, so i wrote you some psudo code above, you have to figure out some things yourself. :)